# Duplication of wordpress user accounts

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to duplicate *Wordpress* user accounts on another blog without resetting passwords?

I am running a company corporate blog on an internal server, only accessible to the company intranet. Due to IT restucturing the blog has to be migrated to a new server.

I am able to move the content and posts and also the user accounts, but the plugin I use does not migrate the passwords. It resets the password, since they are encrypted. Is there any way to migrate the user accounts with the respective passwords?

Comment: WordPress questions about programming and administration are best asked on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

I would comment if I had priveleges, but yet I am ought to answer.

You may copy total db from the db server and site folder from the application server, so all users with their passwords will be copied.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can just copy the passwords from the old installation if you have direct access to both databases.

Answer (score 0):

These are the normal migration process.

- migrate db to the new server
- Copy all files to the new server.
- Change the home_url and site_url to the new server url from the wp_options table
- Login to the new server and refresh the permalinks. Make sure .htaccess has write permissions and mod_rewirte is enabled in your server.
- Install plugin named velvet url and replace the old site url with the new one and click update.

You are done now you will have the exact copy of the site in the new server.